# Finding matches between attribute values and the content of a tag in the XML

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

In that example I need a XSLT stylesheet which returns a list of all `<object>` (including their attributes) but only when their ID values matches to the third `<item>` of `<items>` and the value of `<VIP>` shall be also in that list. A HTML table is the prefered format.

```
<root>
    <items>
        <item>123</item>
        <item>789</item>
        <item>111</item>
        <VIP>42</VIP>       
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>777</item>
        <item>999</item>
        <item>123</item>
        <VIP>43</VIP>       
    </items>
    <parentA ID="222">
        <object ID="123" name="peter">
        </object>
        <object ID="456" name="anton">
        </object>
    </parentA>
    <parentB ID="333">
        <object ID="789" name="marta">
        </object>
        <object ID="111" name="anna">
        </object>
    </parentB>
</root>
```

so at the end the table shall look so:

```
ID   name  VIP
123  peter 43
111  anna  42
```

There is no problem to get the list of the `<object>` elements or the to find the third `<item>` element. But the match between the ID attribute and the value from a certain `<item>` above in the tree is the problem.

Comment: Use a key to resolve cross-references: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option using [`xsl:key`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#key) to select `items` based on the 3rd `item` value.

Using this key we can:

1. Only apply templates to `object`'s whose `ID` attribute matches a key.
2. Get the `VIP` value using the `ID` attribute as the key.

**XSLT**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:key name="items" match="/root/items" use="item[3]"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>VIP</th>
            </tr>
            <!--Corresponds to 1. - Only apply templates to object's whose ID attribute matches a key.--> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*/object[key('items',@ID)]"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="object">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <!--Corresponds to 2. - Get the VIP value using the ID attribute as the key.-->
                <xsl:value-of select="key('items',@ID)/VIP"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>VIP</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>peter</td>
    <td>43</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111</td>
    <td>anna</td>
    <td>42</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH7UCr/1

Comment: I think it would be better to call the key *once* and use the result in `xsl:if` **and** to populate the VIP  table cell.